# Android Google Maps API Key on 2 different machines not working?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am making sure that I'm using the correct key and it works on my personal Vista machine at home, but not on my Mac OSX at work.

Both are using the exact same code base for the app in dropbox, also the keystore is in dropbox so I'm sure that it is the exact same key.

Does anyone know why this is the case? I don't really want to have to use different signing keys on different computers, this would mean that I will only be allowed to compile a signed release version from 1 machine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are talking about `android:apiKey=` key you can use this on any machine.

Comment: How you generated Key using debug key or Release Key?

Comment: what do you mean when you say that it doesn't work?? do you mean that the map is not shown (is blank)?? have you got your map api key using (debug.keystore)?? if this is the case then you'll need to regenerate your maps api key using your own keystore/release key store.

Comment: I am using the debug apiKey(not the live key).
The app loads, but the tiles don't show, and I am getting 

`code 01-19 13:35:38.594: W/System.err(17761):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)`

Comment: Ah! I think @afairplayer has got it. I assume I am using the debug.keystore at home and that is what I generated my gmaps API key from. The one on my mac is different.
I have found out that I can use a custom debug.keystore in Eclipse. Can I just copy the one from home and use that?